# Can not get locations to show in courses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to ruby and I am trying to get the `locations` options that I assign in the form to display in the `course` show page

When i run the command `course.locations= [location]` in rails console it works fine, however how do i get it to show without this command run for each `course`? Am I missing a step somewhere?

**model - course.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
```

**model - location.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<% @course.locations.each do |location| %>
    <%= link_to location.name, courses_path(:id => location.id, :table => "Location") %>
<% end %>

<%= @course.description %>
```

**courses controller**

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  def new
     @course = Course.new
  end

  def index
    @course = Course.all
  end

  def show
   @course = Course.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create

    @course = Course.new(course_perms)

    if @course.valid?
      @course.save
      flash[:success] = "Category Made Successfully - #{@course.name}"
      redirect_to @course
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def course_perms
    params.require(:course).permit([:name, :desc, :locations => [], :categories => []])
  end
end
```

**form**

````
<%= form_for(@course) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :desc %>
  <%= f.text_field :desc, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :locations %>
  <%= f.select :locations, options_from_collection_for_select(@locations, :id, :name, course.locations.ids)%>

  <%= f.label :categories %>
  <%= f.select :categories, options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, :id, :name)%>

  <%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %> ```
````

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your server console, there you could have seen that the update/save action is probably giving you a `parameter not allowed` error. This is because you are whitelisting the wrong parameters:

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  def new
     @course = Course.new
  end

  def index
    @course = Course.all
  end

  def show
   @course = Course.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create

    @course = Course.new(course_perms)

    if @course.valid?
      @course.save
      flash[:success] = "Category Made Successfully - #{@course.name}"
      redirect_to @course
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  #also make this method private
  private

  def course_perms
    params.require(:course).permit([:name, :desc, :location_ids => [], :category_ids => []])
  end
end
```